# IQueryable methods are not resolved for dynamic query variable

Tags: .net, linq, dynamic, c#-4.0

I'm trying to figure out how to use dynamic variables for my methods that use LINQ queries. For example, that works fine:

```
using (DBDataContext db = new DBDataContext()) 
{
    var query = from c in db.Users
                select
                new
                {
                    c.Firstname,
                    c.Lastname,
                    c.Age
                };

    gridUsers.VirtualItemCount = query.Count();
    gridUsers.DataSource = query.ToList();
}
```

But this doesn't work:

```
using (DBDataContext db = new DBDataContext()) 
{
    dynamic query = from c in db.Users
                select
                new
                {
                    c.Firstname,
                    c.Lastname,
                    c.Age
                };

    gridUsers.VirtualItemCount = query.Count();
    gridUsers.DataSource = query.ToList();
}
```

The error is: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Count'. How can I get it working with dynamic keyword?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'd have to use:

```
gridUsers.VirtualItemCount = Queryable.Count(query);
gridUsers.DataSource = Enumerable.ToList(query);
```

Dynamic typing doesn't "do" extension methods. (I'm not *completely* sure why. The compiler stashes a fair amount of information about the call site - it would have to store all the `using` directives associated with the call site too, basically. It would also slow down dynamic binding, which may be the problem they're trying to avoid. Maybe it was just too much work for too little benefit.)

EDIT: Just out of interest, *why* are you trying to use dynamic typing for your sequence in the first place? I suspect you'll find all kinds of things like this become trickier... LINQ depends quite heavily on various bits of type inference.

Note that having an `IQueryable<dynamic>` or an `IEnumerable<dynamic>` is fine, and will work rather better.

Comment: Interesting (maybe) thought - the need to stash `using` could also interfere with the silent unused-reference removal... also some people might complain (perhaps unreasonably) that it leaks code info.

Comment: @Marc: Interesting point about the unused reference removal, yes. Eek. So glad I don't have to use `dynamic` very much :)

Comment: Yes, it is the greatest feature that I never actually use... I guess I/we don't fall into the target group...